# xfs_db reports high file fragmentation where VM is located, but VM shows almost no fragmentation

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, xfs, qcow2, fragmentation

I have several libvirt VMs stored on xfs partitions and am using gluster to replicate the storage. The VMs use qcow2 for storage.

Some of the partitions where the VMs are located indicate high file fragmentation when I run xfs_fb. But the VMs show almost no fragmentation if I run "e4defrag -c /" from their command line.

Does this mean it is safe to ignore what is reported by xfs_db on the host system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct, yet partial, view of the backing file is the one provided by the host system. In other words: if host reports a file as fragmented, it **is** really fragmented, whatever the guest say.

Moreover, as your backing file is a qcow2 image which by itself uses two layers of indirection table, the disk file probably is even **more** fragmented than what `xfs_db` reports.

I suggest you to check your files with `qemu-img check` to have a better understanding of the fragmentation level of each virtual disk.